# accessibility cocoa api to do user actions click on buttons and set value on textfield

Tags: cocoa, ui-automation, uiaccessibility

I have used Accessibility which will allow me to access other apps and UI elements as well. I have used UIElementInspector sample code from Apple's site.

Now if i have

```
<AXApplication: “Sample_mac_application”>
 <AXWindow: “Sample_mac_application”>
  <AXButton: “Button Press”>

Attributes:
   AXRole:  “AXButton”
   AXRoleDescription:  “button”
   AXHelp:  “(null)”
   AXEnabled:  “1”
   AXFocused (W):  “0”
   AXParent:  “<AXWindow: “Sample_mac_application”>”
   AXWindow:  “<AXWindow: “Sample_mac_application”>”
   AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXWindow: “Sample_mac_application”>”
   AXPosition:  “x=468 y=254”
   AXSize:  “w=134 h=32”
   AXTitle:  “Button Press”
   AXIdentifier:  “_NS:51”

Actions:
   AXPress - press
```

How to perform Action press on application.
Is there any way to do it?
CGWindow.h will give information title
You can use CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(). See CGWindow.h
This gives you an array of dictionaries. The following information will probably be useful to you.
position and size: kCGWindowBounds
name: kCGWindowName

I want to perform click, set text operations on elements whose AXRole, AXtitle, AXWindow already known to me using UIElementInspector. I want Xcode cocoa application code not apple script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the accessibilityPerformPress method?

Comment: Hi I have found appium-for-mac automation framework which I can use externally and perform click, set text operations on elements